# Passing data with delegates/protocols

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a UICollectionView with a CollectionReusableView header. I want to pass a string from the collecitonview to the header, so that the header knows which data to load based on the string. I am trying to use delegates/protocols to do this, but keep getting "unexpectedly found nil  while unwrapping an optional value." Here is my code:

```
protocol UserToQuery {
    func thisUser(x: String)
}


class Profile: UICollectionViewController {

    var ownProfile = true
    var delegate:UserToQuery?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.ownProfile == true {
            let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
            self.delegate!.thisUser(username!)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the Header view:

```
class ProfileHeader: UICollectionReusableView, UserToQuery {

    var id1 = String()
    var controller = Profile()


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print(id1)
        controller.delegate? = self
    }

    func thisUser(x: String) {
        self.id1 = x
        getProfileInfo()
    }

    func getUserData() {
        // code here uses the id1 value to get data
    }

}
```

My understanding of delegates/protocols is this: if you want to pass data (i.e., string), to another view, you make the view that receives the string conform to a protocol. This protocol includes a function that is used to pass the string, and when that function is called, it notifies the other view that the string is now available for use, and then you code what you want and use the string. Is that accurate?

Comment: Do you ever set the delegate?

Comment: i edited my comment, that still gives the unexpectedly found nil error

Comment: What line is giving the error? And what object is nil?

Comment: self.delegate!.thisUser(username!) is giving me an error. "username" is not nil, it is what it should be when I set a breakpoint.

Comment: Well you can set `if let` statements to unwrap the delegate and the username variables and use the `else` part of those to print out errors and values. See which one is nil.

Comment: I changed it to self.delegate?.thisUser(username!) and it no longer gives me an error, it just never calls the function in the reusable view. In the reusableheaderview, the line controller.delegate? = self gives me an "EXC bad access." Where can I set the delegate then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ProfileHeader`, you have a variable, `controller`, which is creating a **new** instance of `Profile`, which is **NOT** the `Profile` view controller from your storyboard. This is why `self.delegate!` is `nil` in `Profile.viewDidLoad()`.

I am going to make the assumption that `ProfileHeader` is a view in the `Profile` view controller. In your `viewDidLoad`, you should set the delegate to the `ProfileHeader`. See the example code below (I assume an outlet for the `ProfileHeader` view):

EDIT: `ProfileHeader` is not an outlet, as mentioned in the comments. Updated my answer to reflect that.

```
class Profile: UICollectionViewController {

    var ownProfile = true
    var delegate:UserToQuery?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the delegate!
        self.delegate = ProfileHeader()

        if self.ownProfile == true {
            let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
                // Delegate won't be nil now
                self.delegate!.thisUser(username!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a general flow, the view controller should keep references to the view, not the other way around. So remove the `controller` property from your `ProfileHeader` view. The view shouldn't care what view controller is controlling it.

Comment: profileHeader is not an outlet, but this did lead me to the correct answer. Just change "self.delegate = self.profileHeader" to self.delegate = ProfileHeader()" and then I can mark yours as the correct answer. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have some misunderstandings about protocol/delegate, but it’s normal when you start iOS development.

First of all, why does the app crash :
The variable `delegate` is an optional `UserQuery`. It’s okay for a delegate to be optional, but it’s never set in your code, so when you call :

```
 self.delegate!.thisUser(username!)
```

you try to force unwrapping a nil variable, which results in the crash.

**Protocols**

Now, let’s talk about the protocol/delegate relationship.

You have an `UICollectionViewController` subclass, which embeds an `UICollectionView` object. This `UICollectionView` will be contains a mix of header, footer and cell. Your `ProfileHeader` class will thus be displayed within your `UICollectionView`.

In order to populate an `UICollectionView`, you don’t need to create your own protocol : there are already two protocols for this :

- `UICollectionViewDataSource` is the main protocol to conforms to, because it allows you to populate the collection view
- `UICollectionViewDelegate` is used for further customization of your tableview, i.e. customizing the appearance and handling events.

Since your `Profile` class inherits from `UICollectionViewController`you don’t have to named these protocols after your class name since `UICollectionViewController` already conforms to these protocols as written in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/index.html)

You will have to override the delegate and protocol methods in order to display some data. My advice is, before using headers and footers, to use only `UICollectionViewCell` objects for start easily.

By overriding the method `-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and `- collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, you will be able to populate the collection view.